# mro 3.4.0 bug with install.packages

Tags: r, microsoft-r

There was a bug with the general release of R 3.4.0 that has since been patched for 3.4.0 and also included in 3.4.1, but apparently has not been fixed for mro 3.4.0.  When is the fix/patch going to be available for mro?  What is the work-around besides reverting back to mro 3.3.3?  As it stands now, after installing mro 3.4.0, I cannot install any packages.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054022/installing-package-is-failing-with-error-in-if-file-existsdest-file-mtime) is a similar post on SO for R 3.4.0, but it does not address Microsoft R Open.

[Here](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2017/06/r-341-single-candle-released.html) is an announcement regarding the bug fix for R 3.4.0/1.
*This release fixes a few minor bugs reported after the release of R 3.4.0, including an issue sometimes encountered when attempting to install packages on Windows.*

Note that I also posted at the [MS R Open forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/32f33f7a-d49e-4ae6-8624-8dff40c1f51d/mro-340-bug-with-installpackages?forum=ropen), but figured I might be more likely to get a quick response here.

Thanks,

Kyle

As requested, here is the actual error I get:
[image: Error message]

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting? I know of one which is related to having a file browser open in the directory you are trying to modify, which is easily fixed by closing said browser.

Comment: I edited my original post with the exact error message.

Comment: Yep, that was the error message I was talking about. Do you happen to have any file browsers like explorer open? Having something looking at the directory where packages are installed seems to cause that issue.

Comment: You were right. I closed my windows explorer windows, and voila! It worked. Thanks!  I gave you an up vote.  If you want to add an official answer, I can mark it as such...

Comment: There's generally about a month between a CRAN R release, and when MRO updates to match. So I'd expect MRO 3.4.1 to be announced in about 3 weeks.

Comment: @kyle77 done, glad it worked :)

Comment: @HongOoi Mro 3.4.1has been released: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2017/09/mro-341-now-available.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific error you got is related to some bug in the code that checks for the last modified date of a directory. This returns nothing if there is another application looking at that directory. A file browser for example.

Here is the bugfix specifying what exactly went wrong:

> CHANGES IN R 3.4.0 patched BUG FIXES
>
> ‘file.mtime()’ no longer returns NA on Windows when the file or
>   directory is being used by another process.

http://developer.r-project.org/blosxom.cgi/R-devel/NEWS/2017/04/29#n2017-04-29

Checking for that and closing any such applications should be a workaround for this bug for the time being.

@HongOoi mentioned in the comments that generally there is a month between the CRAN R releases and the following MRO update, so MRO 3.4.1 should take about 3 more weeks.

Update: [Mro 3.4.1has been released](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2017/09/mro-341-now-available.html)